# iOS - Why is UIDatePicker a UIControl subclass while UIPickerView is simply a UIView subclass?

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, uipickerview, uidatepicker

Given that both the classes provide quite similar functionality (differing mainly in the kind of data they let the user select).

What is the potential architectural design decision while led `UIDatePicker` to be created as a `UIControl` subclass while `UIPickerView` to be created simply as a `UIView` subclass?